# Iphone clang error

Tags: iphone

I am trying to send and receive message using XMPP framework. I used XMPPStream class for sending and receiving message. My code to receive message is

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message {

    NSString *msg = [[message elementForName:@"body"] stringValue];
    NSString *from = [[message attributeForName:@"from"] stringValue];
    NSMutableDictionary *m = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [m setObject:msg forKey:@"msg"];
    [m setObject:from forKey:@"sender"];
    [_messageDelegate newMessageReceived:m]; 
    [m release];

}
```

When i build i get a linker error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_XMPPStream", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_XMPPPresence", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Please guide me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unrelated to clang. You are using XMPP Framework for Cocoa (it seems) and not adding the framework. See https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/wiki/GettingStarted_iOS

Comment: But i already added that XMPP framework for cocoa in my project as said in that link.. I am missing something please guide me through this issue.

Comment: Did you add all of the XMPP source files to your project?  They would have names like `XMPPStream.m`.  Or did you add a static library to your project?  It would have a name like `libXMPP.a` or `libXMPPFramework.a`.

Comment: I added all source files and a static library named libidn.a to my project. I could not find any libxmpp.a or libXMPPFramework.a in XMPPFramwork.

Comment: @user1239423 Add libXMPPFramework.a to your "Link Binaries With Libraries" in your Project and Target Settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the problem with adding libraries to your project. Remove all libraries and add it again. Add libidn.a library in the xmppframework and compile it. Follow all the instructions in this link. github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/wiki/GettingStarted_iOS